# UITableView Header View Scrolls

Tags: iphone, uitableview, view, header

I am using a header view, not section header, with my UITableView.  The documentation says that the header view sits on top of the table, but my header view scrolls just like a normal row.  Is there a way to make the header view always visible at the top of the table?

Answer (score 6):

You certainly did found the solution for this, but I'm posting it here for other people.
The table view header and footer views do scroll with the rest of the rows. 
If you want them to have a fixed position on top, or bottom of the table view then you don't really need a header or footer view. 
Just add your desired view as a sibling of the table view (subview of tableView's superView) and position it on top or bottom of the tableView.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to implement:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

and

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

for a fixed header view, not use the self.tableView.tableHeaderView (this one is scrollable).

Comment: There are certain issues with this, though. For instance, if you try this approach with a UISearchBar, each time you type a character into the search field, it will dismiss the keyboard. It seems like interactive elements in a section header doesn't always work as imagined.